# Eslint disable line throws error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I am having an issue with disable-line from eslint... or it might be a bad config.

here is my setup:

```js
.eslintrc
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true
    }
  }
}
```

```js
    this.input.addEventListener('keypress', ({ target: { value } }) => { // eslint-disable-line
      store.dispatch(changeText({ value }));
    });
```

and the result:

> app.tag.js
>       48:54  error  Parsing error: **Unexpected token**

which is exactly the line that I tried to disable,
any ideas what might be causing that?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which feature are you trying to disable?

Comment: You should put `eslint-disable-line` in the same line that you're trying to disable: `store.dispatch(changeText({ value })); // eslint-disable-line`

Comment: ^^ Indeed, or replace what you have with `eslint-disable-next-line`.

Comment: `store.dispatch(changeText({ event.target.value }));` why don't you just use it as this

Comment: The error is a *parsing error*, so I don't think `esline-disable-line` or `eslint-disable-next-line` is going to help; even when you're disabling rules, ESLint still has to be able to parse the code.

Comment: I made a typo on the example, so the line that I want do disable is the one with `({ target: { value } })`, thats where error is being throw

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly: That's invalid syntax, it would have to be `store.dispatch(changeText({ value: event.target.value }));` or `let value = event.target.value; store.dispatch(changeText({ value }));`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, still i was sayin just why don't he use longer way

Comment: This is interesting. On astexplorer.net, both `espree` and `babel-eslint` are able to parse that. Maybe it's not picking up your config file for some reason? If you run `eslint` with the `--debug` flag, does it show that it's using your `.eslintrc`?

Answer (score 3):

It's a **parsing error**. `eslint-disable-line` tells ESLint to disable its rules for a line, but ESLint still has to be able to *parse* the code.

The line in question:

```
this.input.addEventListener('keypress', ({ target: { value } }) => {
```

...relies on the parser understanding complex ES2015 destructured arguments. Apparently the version of ESLint you're using doesn't understand how to parse those (yet). (Your syntax is valid, so it's not an issue at your end. It's the ESLint parser.)

Comment: seems like so! btw the version that I am using is: `2.9.0` :)